# Codeigniter HTML Caching with Dynamic Content

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, caching

I have an application where I use ajax to update the comments & Like count.

I am using Codeigniter page caching http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

and set following code to recreate caching every 60 minutes

```
$this->output->cache(60);
```

Problem is when somebody enter a new comment, DB operation is happening (Because of Ajax call), But the Newly inserted comment disappears after the page refresh, because of the cached HTML page. How to handle caching and also dynamic content to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

To delete a cache file you need to use the following function

```
$this->output->delete_cache('CONTROLLER/FUNCTION');
```

Note: No Slash before or after.

In my Case i was using custom routes in codeigniter. When user type example.com it is routed to example.com/CONTROLLER/FUNCTIONNAME and that too default landing page.

So i created a new function. Please [refer here](http://mycodde.blogspot.com/2015/04/deleting-codeigniter-webpage-cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of caching is to save server resources on page load (i.e. so the server doesn't need to fetch all the dynamic data every time its loaded).

It sounds like you are using the AJAX function to both submit the data but also modify the webpage on the client side simultaneously. When the user then refreshes the page, this will fetch the content back from the server, in this case the original cached content that was generated before the comment was made and is therefore operating exactly as it should.

If you have a true requirement for caching this page, you could consider deleting the cache, which would force it to be rebuilt on the next page load whenever a comment is made. Placing the following line of code in your controller (in the function that received the AJAX data) should do it:

```
$this->output->delete_cache('foo/bar');
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is /foo/bar ?  I twied controller/function name its not deleting.

Comment: @abdulrashid yes I believed it should be controller/function but I've not personally tested it; I just got this information from the CI docs, I'll build a small example now to test and let you know soon.

Comment: Could you confirm which version of CodeIgniter you are using?

Comment: I am using CI 3. I am reading http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

Comment: Ok the function doesn't exist in CI 2.2, but does in CI 3; Having just tested this locally, it seems the preceding / is the problem before the controller. Try changing to just 'foo/bar' where foo = controller and bar = function  that loads your view (i.e. not the ajax function)

Comment: I have created a function         `function update_cache(){
            $this->output->delete_cache("welcome/home");
        }` But it is not working

Comment: You could just place this code in the function that receives you ajax call rather than having it as a separate function

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the solution.